# Keras - method on_batch_end is slow but only callback I have is checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, callback, keras

I set up a network with keras using TensorFlow backend.

When I train my network I often times keep getting message:

```
UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (0.195523). Check your callbacks.
  % delta_t_median)
```

The issue is that my network is set up with only checkpoint callback:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
```

As far as I see in documentation this method is called only on epoch end, so it can't slow down `on_batch_end` method. Can anyone provide some information on what is the issue?

Comment: Are you using a generator, that might register an implicit callback.

Comment: @briantyler, yes, I did use the generator. It was rather slow (was delivering a batch of images randomly selected from a folder). But are you saying that generators get registered as "On batch end"?

Comment: I was just speculating, seems reasonable though.

Comment: And what's the solution?

Comment: @IsaacSim no solution. The message is just confusing, actually it was related to generator (which was picking files for training) being slower than training of model. I managed to slightly speed it up by rewriting it + I started to use larger models which train longer on each batch so the message disappeared

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most probably a Generator (`fit_generator()`) issue. When using a generator as data source it has to be called at the end of a batch. Consider revisiting your generator code, using multiprocessing (`workers > 1`) or a higher batchsize (if possible)